# I've made a git mistake and I can't seem to fix it.

Tags: git

I have 3 machines:

Laptop, Desktop, Server

There are two branches I'm working with: next and regroup. regroup is pristine, and I want it to become the new next.

Timeline of events:

```
 1. I finish the last changes to regroup on Desktop and push them to Server
 2. I pull from server to laptop
 3. On, laptop I checkout next (next happens to be 2 commits ahead of server/next)
 // I want to take all the regroup changes and completly overwrite the next changes. 
 // I think this command will work (i'm not actually sure what it really did)
 4. Laptop: git merge -s recursive -X theirs regroup
 5. Laptop: git push
 6. Oh no, I forgot to test before push. Quick test. Things break. 
 7. Laptop: git checkout regroup; git reset --hard HEAD. Test. Things still break. 
 // Ok, I'll just switch to my desktop whichi still works, and get that perfect branch back. 
 8. Desktop: Test, things still work. git checkout -b reset_final; git push origin reset_final
 10. Laptop: git pull; git checkout reset_final. Test. Things still break!? Why!?
```

So, right now, my server and laptop seem to be screwed. My desktop still has the branch I want under regroup and regroup_final, but I don't know how to reset it to that on the server.

What I want to do is make my desktop's regroup the server's next. I want to completely blow away the stupid pushes that I did to the server. I'm confused, and I could use some help.

Answer (score 0):

```
git merge -s recursive -X theirs regroup
```

This will choose "theirs" when there is a conflict.  But "our" non-conflicting changes are kept.

```
git reset --hard HEAD
```

This will undo any changes in your working directory.  However, since your merge was already committed, it probably didn't undo anything.  You can rollback the last commit with:

```
git reset --hard HEAD^
```

For your last point, that way of copying `reset_final` would not copy uncommitted changes.  Are there uncommitted changes on your desktop?  Check with:

```
git status
```

Comment: There are no uncommited changes. The reset --hard HEAD^ did not work. It seems like the changes were made in an earlier part of the commit tree by next which overwrote goood things in regroup.